# How to create directory ranging from 1 to nth?

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir

In my scenario, I have some photos and I want to keep them separate. At present, I am doing `mkdir gallery1 gallery2 gallery3 gallery4 gallery5 gallery6`, but this is a pain. I think we can do it more easily. Suppose I want to make directories from *gallery7* to *gallery50*. How would I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With brace expansion.

```
mkdir gallery{1..50}
```

Comment: with a leading zero would be `mkdir gallery{01..50}`

Answer (score 5):

While there are already fine answers, and you have already started, I'll throw mine in anyway.

I always prefer to make numerically sequenced files with leading zeros, like so:

```
mkdir $(printf "gallery%02d\n" {1..50})
```

This will give you directories `gallery01` through `gallery50`. This helps to keep them nicely aligned and in the correct order when sorting.

Comment: In newer version of bash you can do `mkdir gallery{01..50}` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @otokan, wow, thanks! tested in bash 4.2.39(1) in fedora 18, it works!

Answer (score 4):

As the already mentioned *brace expansion* isn't supported by all shells you can also use `seq` from the `coreutils` instead:

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 50)
do
    mkdir "gallery$i"
done
```

Option `-w` is for *equal width*, i.e. creating *gallery01*, *gallery02* etc.

Comment: No need for the loop: `seq -f 'mkdir gallery%02g' 50 | sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brace expansion in a bash script. The following creates the directories gallery7 to gallery50 in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {5..70}
do
   mkdir "gallery$i"
done
```

Comment: You are right, but its cumbersome to create a script for tasks like this. :) Specially if shorter solutions already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try first, what it will resolve in with:

```
seq -f 'mkdir gallery%g' 50
```

before you pipe the output to the shell with:

```
seq -f 'mkdir gallery%g' 50 | sh
```

This creates folders with a leading zero:

```
seq -f 'mkdir gallery%02g' 50 | sh
```